# General structure of android app

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im searching to make a simple android app that can do two things:

1. Show incomming bluetooth data on a graph
2. Send user defined data back using a textbox and a button

I'm using the navigation drawer, and loosely based on a tutorial, I've set up a GUI with two fragments, each running their own activity.

My question is now, where would I put all the bluetooth related stuff? Each fragment must be able to both send and receive data, will I have to implement the bluetooth connection in each activity? Can I implement it in one activity (e.g. mainactivity) and reach it from the other activities? Is there a better way to do this (i.e. two fragments from one activity)?

**Update:** 
Maybe I'm confusing myself a bit. What I currently have is a main-activity, (`extends Activity`) that starts one of two fragments (`extends fragment`) by calling

> fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
>   MyFragment.newInstance()).commit()

So this is actually one activity only, I guess. Question is still, will I put bluetooth related stuff in the mainActivity, or in the fragment-classes that are created. Do I even need the fragment-classes, or can the xml-fragment layouts be handled from within the mainActivity instead?

Comment: why don´t you run both fragments from the same activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to implement a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), which you can reach from any of your activities or fragments.

Alternatively, you can have a singleton object somewhere which manages this connection, but this can create more complicated lifecycle issues, so I would recommend simply using a service.

Comment: A service might be what I'm looking for, but I updated my question, since I think I confused myself quite a bit :)